# Adding onClick event handler to Silverlight control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-3.0, xap

My web site consumes a silverlight application using the application's xap file. Is it possible to catch the 'onclick' event that occurs when the user clicks on the silverlight control? I would like to re-focus the screen so that only the control is visible when this happens.

I have control over both the silverlight code and the web site code, so a solution from either direction would be equally appreciated.

Please note that I am very new to Silverlight so if any of the above sounded 'n00b-y'... well, it was. Forgive me :)

Comment: you need your silverlight control to make a call back to the page calling a javascript function. Then you can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out your main XAML file of your Silverlight application by checking the RootVisual assignment statement in App.xaml.cs file.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    **this.RootVisual = new MainPage();**
}
```

By default, MainPage.xaml.cs is the first `UserControl` to be loaded on Application Startup.

Attach an event handler to the `UserControl.MouseLeftButtonDown` event in the MainPage constructor

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    **this.MouseLeftButtonDown += MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown;**
}
```

In the event hander, invoke your javascript method "refocusScreen" (you need to implement this method the re-focus the screen) using [Html Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
void MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // About [Invoke][2] method
    **HtmlPage.Document.Invoke("refocusScreen");**

    // detach event handler so that this won't call the JS method everytime the Mouse left button goes down.
    this.MouseLeftButtonDown -= MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown;
}
```